# Video or Videopath can't get processed because of memory mapping

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I want to process a video using OpenCV and display the program in a Qt-GUI. When I try to open the video with `cv::VideoCapture` it creates a memory mapping error.

Here is the debug message:

```
undefined(DEBUG) V4L: opening /mnt/8668734168732F55/Development/logo_detection/videos/vid_5.mp4
(DEBUG) V4L2: Unable to query capability. try_init_v4l2 open "/mnt/8668734168732F55/Development/logo_detection/videos/vid_5.mp4": The argument is invalid
/mnt/8668734168732F55/Development/logo_detection/videos/vid_5.mp4 does not support memory mapping
```

On my laptop (Ubuntu 20.04) I can run the program perfectly fine, but on my desktop (Ubuntu 18.04) the above happens. Do I have some sort of driver not installed?

**Edit_01**:

When I tried to run cv::VideoCapture alone with the video i get these results:

```
init done
[ INFO:0] global /mnt/8668734168732F55/Libraries/opencv-4.1.2/modules/videoio/src/videoio_registry.cpp (187) VideoBackendRegistry VIDEOIO: Enabled backends(6, sorted by priority): FFMPEG(1000); GSTREAMER(990); INTEL_MFX(980); V4L2(970); CV_IMAGES(960); CV_MJPEG(950)
[ INFO:0] global /mnt/8668734168732F55/Libraries/opencv-4.1.2/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (329) getPluginCandidates VideoIO pluigin (FFMPEG): glob is 'libopencv_videoio_ffmpeg*.so', 1 location(s)
[ INFO:0] global /mnt/8668734168732F55/Libraries/opencv-4.1.2/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (336) getPluginCandidates     - /mnt/8668734168732F55/Libraries/opencv-4.1.2/build/lib: 0
[ INFO:0] global /mnt/8668734168732F55/Libraries/opencv-4.1.2/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (340) getPluginCandidates Found 0 plugin(s) for FFMPEG
[ INFO:0] global /mnt/8668734168732F55/Libraries/opencv-4.1.2/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (329) getPluginCandidates VideoIO pluigin (GSTREAMER): glob is 'libopencv_videoio_gstreamer*.so', 1 location(s)
[ INFO:0] global /mnt/8668734168732F55/Libraries/opencv-4.1.2/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (336) getPluginCandidates     - /mnt/8668734168732F55/Libraries/opencv-4.1.2/build/lib: 0
[ INFO:0] global /mnt/8668734168732F55/Libraries/opencv-4.1.2/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (340) getPluginCandidates Found 0 plugin(s) for GSTREAMER
[ INFO:0] global /mnt/8668734168732F55/Libraries/opencv-4.1.2/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (329) getPluginCandidates VideoIO pluigin (INTEL_MFX): glob is 'libopencv_videoio_intel_mfx*.so', 1 location(s)
[ INFO:0] global /mnt/8668734168732F55/Libraries/opencv-4.1.2/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (336) getPluginCandidates     - /mnt/8668734168732F55/Libraries/opencv-4.1.2/build/lib: 0
[ INFO:0] global /mnt/8668734168732F55/Libraries/opencv-4.1.2/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (340) getPluginCandidates Found 0 plugin(s) for INTEL_MFX
(DEBUG) V4L: opening ../videos/vid_5.mp4
[ INFO:0] global /mnt/8668734168732F55/Libraries/opencv-4.1.2/modules/videoio/src/cap_images.cpp (282) icvExtractPattern Pattern: ../videos/vid_%01d.mp4 @ 5
```

And this is the corresponding code:

```cpp
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    VideoCapture capture;


    namedWindow("window");
    moveWindow("window", 1500, 0);

    cv::Mat image;        

    // load videofile
    capture.open("../videos/vid_5.mp4");
    if (capture.isOpened())
    {
        cout << "Capture is opened" << endl;
        // Video loop for grabbing images
        for (;;)
        {
            // grabbing image
            capture >> image;

            if (image.empty())
                break;

            imshow("window", image);


            // press any key to break the loop
            if (waitKey(10) >= 0)
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you tried ```VideoCapture``` outside of qt, does it work fine?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I updated the Question. Now VideoCapture is isolated, but still produces an error.

Comment: Can you try the command: ```sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev``` and also you may try to install [gstreamer plugins](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html?gi-language=c)

Comment: I installed ```sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-qt5 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio``` and ```sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev```, but still get the same error.

Comment: Here are similar problems to your problem : [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/16278) and [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-distribution-of-openvino-toolkit/topic/851891). Your problem probably about ffmpeg version or not installed. You can try [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-ubuntu-18-04/) to install for ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I solved the problem with deleting my opencv build folder and reinstalling with all the things I downloaded earlier. Thanks for the help @YunusTemurlenk !

Comment: Happy to hear you solved it. But what was the opencv version you are using and did you install the same version again?

Comment: I originally had version 4.1.2. Then I switched to 4.1.0 and had the same issue, but installed the plugins you recommended. When I had no luck with that too I tried looking for errors and discovered, that ffmpeg and gstreamer was not found ```FFMPEG:                      NO``` ```GStreamer:                   NO (1.14.5)```. I deleted the build folder and tried again. Now that ```FFMPEG:                      YES``` ```GStreamer:                   YES (1.14.5)``` was showing and I configured everything for my liking again except this time I went with ```WITH_QT=OFF```. I then proceeded normal.